# Formatting table display in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I have a [table](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) with different type of columns. I am exporting this to excel with the function `writetable(...)`. I was however wondering how I could display some columns in a different format.

E.g. the format in % rounded up to 2 integers. E.g. `0.025` --> `2.5%`.

```
T = table;
T.('Test') = rand(100,1,1);
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is if it is formatted like that in your table. You can also open excel via Matlab and programmatically format it there but it's a lot more cumbersome.

```
t = array2table(rand(3))
t.(3) = cellstr(num2str(t.(3)*100, '%4.2f%%'))
writetable(t, 'test.csv')
```

t =

```
 Var1        Var2       Var3  
_______    ________    _______

0.73634     0.70405    0.33086
0.39471     0.44231    0.42431
0.68342    0.019578    0.27027
```

t =

```
 Var1        Var2        Var3  
_______    ________    ________

0.73634     0.70405    '33.09%'
0.39471     0.44231    '42.43%'
0.68342    0.019578    '27.03%'
```